# Mesh doesn't have geometry three.js

Tags: rotation, three.js

According this topic : [Rotating .obj file OBJMTLLoader three.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22277081/rotating-obj-file-objmtlloader-three-js)

I can change the pivot of my obj according this code :

```
    loader.load('models/motor12.obj', 'models/motor12.mtl', function (object) {
            object.traverse(function (child) {
        console.log(child);
                child.centroid = new THREE.Vector3();
                for (var i = 0, l = child.geometry.vertices.length; i < l; i++) {
                    child.centroid.add(child.geometry.vertices[i].clone());
                }
                child.centroid.divideScalar(child.geometry.vertices.length);
                var offset = child.centroid.clone();
                child.geometry.applyMatrix(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(-offset.x, -offset.y, -offset.z));
                child.position.copy(child.centroid);
                child.geometry.computeBoundingBox();
            });
    scene.add( object );

    }, onProgress, onError);
```

Unfortanutelly, I have the error :

TypeError: child.geometry is undefined

I put a console.log(child) and effectively, child doesn't have geometry :

[image]

What have I missed?

Thanks

Comment: If you look at the comments of the post you reference use `if (geometry !== undefined)`

Comment: I've seen it, but if geometry == undefined, what I'm supposed to do ?

Comment: there might be some null objects in there.